# Readlines outputting all sentences within a for loop

Tags: python, counter, readline

I'm trying to output sentences in a file in the format of:

line 1: first sentence,
line 2: second sentence,
line 3: third sentence,

etc.

Yet the code I'm inputting is giving back as so:

line 1: all of the sentences,
line 2: all of the sentences,

etc.

I have no idea whether there is a problem in the readline or if it's in the for loop, can anybody help? I've included the script below

```
import re, sys

f = open('findallEX.txt', 'r')

lines = f.readlines()

for l in lines:
    sys.stdout.write('line %s: %s' %(ii, lines))

    ii = ii + 1

print l
```

Comment: fyi, python has a `+=` operator

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, you code could be written much more simply:

```
with open('findallEX.txt') as f:
     for ii,line in enumerate(f):
         sys.stdout.write('line %s: %s' %(ii,line))
```

The `with` statement is a fancy way of doing the following<sup>1</sup>:

```
f = open(...)
#stuff inside with block
f.close()
```

Also, please note that you can iterate over a file object directly.  `readlines()` is deprecated (and removed in python3.x).  Finally, python provides the `enumerate` function for keeping a counter while iterating.  This will also remove the `NameError` that your code has if you copy/paste it since you use `ii` before you actually define it.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Actually, `with` does a lot more than that.  It also makes sure your file gets closed properly even in the case where the code block raises an exception for example.  See comment by Martijn for a more correct translation.</sup>

Comment: It's a fancy way of doing `f = None`, `try: f = open(...)` followed by `finally:`, `if f is not None: f.close()`, to be pedantic about it. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I suppose that's fair enough, but I'm trying to explain it in *simple* terms for the benefit of OP (and so the answer qualifies for the adjective "useful").

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this.

```
with open('findallEX.txt') as f:
    for line_num, line_text in enumerate(f):
        sys.stdout.write('line %d: %s' % (line_num, line_text))
```

---

If you are not sure about the methods used above:

- `with` : http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm
- `enumerate` : http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 1):

Change the loop as:

```
for l in lines:
    sys.stdout.write('line %s: %s' %(ii, l))
    ii = ii + 1
```

The variable "lines" is a list of lines, you use "for l in lines" to travel each line in it. And the varaible "l" means a single line.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Works now!